# while loop doesn't loop to the right place

Tags: java, while-loop

SO here is the problem I'm running into: 
the while loop doesn't loop back to where I want it to, It's supposed to prompt for vehicle type after the user is done with the first entry, but instead it goes to the number of miles.

```
String vehicleType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
"Enter the type of vehicle or Q to quit ");

 while (!vehicleType.equalsIgnoreCase ("Q")) {

       if (!(vehicleType.equalsIgnoreCase ("car")
          || vehicleType.equalsIgnoreCase ("truck")
          || vehicleType.equalsIgnoreCase ("suv")
          || vehicleType.equalsIgnoreCase ("motorcycle")))
     {

      validData = false;
      vehicleType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
      "Please enter a valid vehicle type from the assigned list ");
    }
    else {
        validData = true;  
    do {
        try { 

             milesTraveled = Double.parseDouble (JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null, "Enter number of miles to be traveled ")); }


          catch (NumberFormatException e)
```

Comment: I think you are missing some code here.

Comment: this isnt part of your question but just a suggestion if you make validData = false before the while loop you would only need to change it when it is true. which means that your code most likely has no need for it at all (unless this is all wrapped inside some other kind of loop which I cant imagine it is)

Comment: You are asking the user to enter the Vehicle type inside a statement that is checking to see if the vehicle type is "car", "truck", "suv" or "motorcycle".  The issue here is if you don't set it to something invalid at the end of the loop, it wont go in the if. I would remove the if statement, grab the JDialog and make it display a ComoboBox with valid types in it. Make it so that it checks to see if the user has entered cancel, and then exit the loop that way. [Good tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for setting up different Dialog types here.

Comment: After copying the code you have written here and testing it: If i enter Q it exits the program, if i enter one of the allowed vehicles it goes to the milage, if i enter a random string (and invalid entry) it asks me to enter one from the allowed list. So it seems to be working for me.

Comment: @yitzih yes it works for the first set of values, But it's supposed to ask for the second set of information starting with the vehicle type, but it goes immediately to the miles traveled in the 2nd run

Comment: @Aziz What second set of information?

Comment: @yitzih it's supposed to continue prompting for input until "Q" is entered

Comment: Remove the if statement asking for the user to input the car type, this is your issue. Then use a combo box for the user to select the vehicle type. If you don't want to do that, then when you get the input from the user from the Dialog box, THEN use the if statement to determine if it was valid.

Comment: once the vehicleType has valid info its not going to enter the if statement (since its false) which is where it asks the user to enter data and it will go straight to the else statement which asks for the mileage

Comment: @Stevo I'm not allowed to use combo box, plus my problem isn't with the validation, when the user enter the first set on inputs it works fine, but when it's time for the second set of input it doesn't ask for vehicle type and it assumes that it's the same type

Comment: @yitzih I think you are right, what do I do to fix that?

Comment: Why do you need them to enter Q after they have entered valid information? The current way you have it designed if you make them enter Q then the vehicle type will be changed to Q and you will lose whatever car type was already stored (again bad design and a likely source of future bugs)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Keep requesting Vehicle details from user
while(user wants to keep going)
{
    boolean userQuit = false

    //Continue requesting Vehcile type until valid OR until user wants to quit
    while(user has not entered Q or valid car type)
    {
        answer = prompt user to enter type with your Dialog

        if(answer entered is "q")
        {
            userQuit = true
            break;
        }
        else if(answer IS one of the vehicle types)
        {
            Assign answer to vehicle type
            break;
        }
    }

    if(userQuit)
            break;

    //The rest of your code. Make sure to set userQuit back to false
}
```

Ok, so what we have here is basic pseudo code of what you should change your order of events to. See how I am asking the user for input BEFORE I am checking to see if it is valid. This means on the second time, it will ask again.

You will need to decide what you would like to do in the case that they do no enter valid data. I would probably write a while loop around the Dialog prompt and the if statement to determine whether the input is valid, and if not, just ask again.

After reading Yitzih's comment, it is worth actually noting that you would need to apply to the car type AFTER the Vehicle type has been confirmed to be valid. I have edited the code with the other while loop to make it easier to see what is necessary.

I also agree that using "Q" as the exit condition is not particularly good, but if this is the design decision you have been left with, then the above pseudo code will satisfy that need.